# Windows 7 allow pinning exe on network share to taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am just configuring my new Windows 7 work machine and have discovered that I can't pin an exe on a network drive to the taskbar. Are there any work arounds to this e.g. Registry Edits.

I can understand the reasoning it's not allowed by default for newbies as the network location may later not exist but I am certain it always will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make a shortcut that points to the network location and pin that to the taskbar?

Maybe these links have some help? (link removed)

http://kacnje.blogspot.com/2009/10/mystery-solved-pin-network-application.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of names that if they are contained within the exe then it cannot be pinned:

Documentation;Help;Install;More Info;Readme;Read me;Read First;Setup;Support;What's New;Remove

[Source](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/32765.aspx)